# ProcessBuilder&Runtime exec could not find or load main class in Spring Project

Tags: spring-mvc, java-8, processbuilder, runtime.exec

I want to compile a java file and exec its class in another class ( ← This class is a @service of a Spring MVC project ).

The service code is:

```
@Service
public class MRServiceImp implements MRService {
    @Override
    public String submitMR(int id, String fd) {
        try {
            // compile the java file
            String[] cmd = {"javac", "P" + id + ".java"};
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
            pb.directory(new File(fd));
            Process p = pb.start();

            // exec the class file
            String[] execmd = {"java", "P" + pz_id};
            ProcessBuilder epb = new ProcessBuilder(execmd);
            epb.directory(new File(fd));
            p = epb.start();

            // get normal output
            BufferedReader pin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String ptmp = pin.readLine();
            while (ptmp != null) {
                pout = pout == null ? ptmp + '\n' : pout + ptmp + '\n';
                ptmp = pin.readLine();
            }

            // get error output
            pin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            String wout = null;
            ptmp = pin.readLine();
            while (ptmp != null) {
                wout = wout == null ? ptmp + '\n' : wout + ptmp + '\n';
                ptmp = pin.readLine();
            }

            // print output
            System.out.println(pout);
            System.out.println(wout);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null; // for test
    }
```

When this Service is invoked, I always get a Error: Could not find or load main class: P[id]

I cd theFilePath, the P[id].class file is existing.
And I can run java P[id] successfully in theFilePath.

And I try to replace ProcessBuilder with Runtime, like:

```
@Service
public class MRServiceImp implements MRService {
    @Override
    public String submitMR(int id, String fd) {
        try {
            // compile the java file
            String[] cmd = {"javac", "P" + id + ".java"};
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
            pb.directory(new File(fd));
            Process p = pb.start();

            // exec the class file
            String execmd = "java", fd + "/P" + pz_id;
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(execmd);

            // get normal output
            BufferedReader pin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String ptmp = pin.readLine();
            while (ptmp != null) {
                pout = pout == null ? ptmp + '\n' : pout + ptmp + '\n';
                ptmp = pin.readLine();
            }

            // get error output
            pin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            String wout = null;
            ptmp = pin.readLine();
            while (ptmp != null) {
                wout = wout == null ? ptmp + '\n' : wout + ptmp + '\n';
                ptmp = pin.readLine();
            }

            // print output
            System.out.println(pout);
            System.out.println(wout);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null; // for test
    }
```

I get the same Error again T^T

IDE is sts-bundle, server is tomcat8

Answer (score 1):

I know what is wrong here.

pb.start(); does not mean the command of pb will be executed immediately.

So if I set pb of command javac hello.java; set epb of command java hello

And I call pb.start(); epb.start(); continuously, I will get an Error: could not find or load main class: hello, because when I exec epb.start(); The former command(pb.start) may have not been executed!

I got 2 solution:

First: set a finally field and exec epb.start() in this field, like:

```
@Service
public class MRServiceImp implements MRService {
@Override
public String submitMR(int id, String fd) {
    try {
        // compile the java file
        String[] cmd = {"javac", "P" + id + ".java"};
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
        pb.directory(new File(fd));
        Process p = pb.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // exec the class file
        String[] execmd = {"java", "P" + pz_id};
        ProcessBuilder epb = new ProcessBuilder(execmd);
        epb.directory(new File(fd));
        Process p = epb.start();
    }
    return null; // for test
}
```

Second: a trick of bash

```
@Service
public class MRServiceImp implements MRService {
@Override
public String submitMR(int id, String fd) {
    try {
        // compile & exec the java file
        String[] cmd = {"/bin/bash"};
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
        pb.directory(new File(fd));
        Process p = pb.start();
        BufferedWriter pbw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
        pbw.write("javac *.java;java P" + pz_id+";exit;");
        pbw.newLine();
        pbw.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null; // for test
}
```

I use the second one.